# DNS leak when using OpenVPN on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to VPN server using provided config, but the problem is that config works great on Windows, but on Linux (I have kubuntu 20.04) I'm experiencing DNS leakage. My IP address is being changed but my provider still blocks some resources. I'm connecting to the same server with the same protocol and port, the config file is also the same.
What have I tried:

- from OpenVPN guide I added such lines to my config:

```
    script-security 2
    up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
    down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

- I also tried to configure `iptables` setting OUTPUT policy to DROP and adding accept rule for the server I'm trying to connect.

None of the options worked for me and I still can't access blocked resources, also sites like dnsleaktest detect two dns servers, one from the server I'm connecting to and one from my provider.

Why is that happening while everything work on Windows? Is it possible to fix and if so - how?

My config:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote <server i'm connecting to> <port>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1300
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 45
ping-timer-rem
key-direction 1
mute 10
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
verify-client-cert
```